# Convert Array of objects to Array with only values

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, object

I have an array (obj_values) of objects

```
[
#<User id: 1, name: "Kostas">,
#<User id: 2, name: "Moufa">,
...
]
```

And I want to convert this into an Array with only the values from above objects, so it will look like:

```
[
    1, Kostas
    2, Moufa
]
```

I can do it like this:

```
obj_table = []
obj_values.each do |ext|
          ext.each do |obj|
            obj_table.push([obj.id, obj.name].join(","))
          end
end
```

However with this approach I need to explicitly specify what attributes I want to push (obj.id and obj.name), is there a way to push whole data from object without the need to specify each attribute separately?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attributes` to get a hash of all the attributes on the model. Call `.values` on it to get just the values without the keys.

Using your code:

```
obj_table = []
obj_values.each do |ext|
  ext.each do |obj|
    obj_table.push(obj.attributes.values.join(","))
  end
end
```

Though there are better ways. I suggest you look into `.map` and `.flat_map`.

```
obj_table = obj_values.flat_map do |ext|
  ext.map do |obj|
    obj.attributes.values.join(",")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can push data without specifying it separately. to push data you have to use an `object.attributes.values`
an **object** will be your active record object.
**attributes** will return a hash with all attributes of that object.
so you can change your loops into a single statement like:

```
obj_values.flat_map {|object_value|  object_value.attributes.values }
```